# Why does the aspect ratio in Transformers: The Last Knight change?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series

In *Transformers: The Last Knight*, the fifth film in Michael Bay's *Transformers* series, the aspect ratio change multiple times, [often within scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uED8CYDB7e4). Of course, I am not referring to changing from regular to IMAX for the sake of action--the ratio changes within a scene of two people having a conversation. It's frankly distracting, and I would like to know the reason why this happens. I don't remember this happening in the rest of the movies in Bay's series.

Comment: Because it's a terrible, terrible film.

Comment: @Valorum, some of the worst editing I have ever seen. I remember that my eyes hurt after watching the movie and I also had a headache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the film's director of photography, it's because Michael Bay likes to use different camera types for different types of shots.

> That's right, the Transformers: The Last Knight trailer has eight
> different aspect ratios. As we learned on set, that's because they're
> shooting with a bunch of different formats. Director of photography
> **Jonathan Sela explained to us that Michael Bay likes to mix up the
> format quite a bit.** The cameras on set include the Red 6K Weapon
> Dragon, the Alexa 65 IMAX rig and the IMAX Phantom 65, all of which
> are 3D cameras. In addition, there are several 2D cameras, some with
> spherical optics, some GoPro footage and also some stuff shot on film.
> So prepare to see the aspect ratio change a lot throughout the movie.
>
> <sub><sup>['Transformers: The Last Knight' Trailer Breakdown: What The Hell Is Going On Here?](https://www.slashfilm.com/548136/transformers-the-last-knight-trailer-breakdown/?utm_campaign=clip)</sup></sub>